# Can't use more than 10 cores in sciki learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use sciki-learn(0.17.1) on server with 32 cores. The OS is Ubuntu 14.04.1 and python version is 2.7.12. When I tried to run something like

```
etr_init = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs = -1)
etr_model = etr_init.fit(trn_x, y)
```

only 10 cores were running. Is there any other configuration needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most algorithms in sklearn only support parallelism on the fit-level (meaning: each fit is using one core). This helps especially in cross-validation and grid-search.

Luckily for you, you are using some algorithm which is easily parallelized (a natural characteristic of ensemble-methods) and got some special multiprocessing-treatment which is more fine than the fit-level approach.

In your case, creating `RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1)` uses the default of:

`n_estimators : integer, optional (default=10)`.

As **the parallelization-capabilities** of sklearn in regards to `RandomForestRegressor` are limited to **different Trees (the inner components)**, you can only use 10 cores (as you are using 10 x Trees = `10 x DecisionTreeRegressor`).

Using:

```
etr_init = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=32, n_jobs = -1)
etr_model = etr_init.fit(trn_x, y)
```

would probably use more cores.

It's still questionable if 32 cores are used as SMT/HT-cores are not always counted (and may be existent on your cluster). *Not always* does not mean that it's indeterministic within sklearn, but different thread/multiprocessing libraries use different rules and i don't know how sklearn or the inner component used = joblib is working (non-related popular example: x264 used 1.5 * total-cores (incl. HT) as i remember).

My conjecture about sklearn only using multiprocessing on the level of `#-trees` can be deduced from looking at the docs (while knowing what RandomForests are):

- [DecisionTreeRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor) does not support the argument `n_jobs`. (each estimator of some RandomForestRegressor is a DecisionTreeRegressor)